# How to properly use ChunkListener when the step is item-oriented?

Tags: spring-batch

I have an item-oriented step and I'd like to run some code on my items after transaction has been commited.

In this case, how could I access items in a ChunkListener? Can I use step execution context? Would be nice if it were thread-safe...

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but for my case, I am seeing a large time gap after `write` method is finished and when `LAST_UPDATED` is updated in meta data table. Do you know why that gap might be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch doesn't have a listener for that phase (after commit) but Spring does.  You should be able to use the `TransactionalEventListener` to execute your logic after a commit.

You can read more about that listener in the blog post announcing it here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

Answer (score 0):

You should use `afterWrite(java.util.List<? extends S> items)` method of  `ItemWriteListener` since items to be written are accessible there.

Comment: The problem is that afterWrite runs before the transaction commits and, in my case, items will be queued for further processing, so it would bring some race conditions that are hard to handle, at this time.